# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake in production server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting error in production server and same code is running fine in test server with out any errors.

**A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.)**
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

[image]

Comment: Disable encrypt connection from your connection string.

Comment: Can you check if there is any difference of ASP.NET version on your test and prod servers? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742054/the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a-common-a

Comment: If you're trying to use TLS 1.1 or 1.2, then they require .Net framework 4.5 on the server