# ErrorMessage:Exchange error:The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Tags: c#, .net

I have .NET program that takes attachments from a particular mailbox id and processes the attachment file.

The problem is we have enables TLS 1.2 and disabled all old versions on windows server. Since then we are facing the following error while trying to communicate with exchange server through my .NET program.

```
ErrorMessage:Exchange error: The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. 
 InnerExceptionSystem.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
```

below are files I have in my program:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.dll
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.pdb
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.xml
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.pdb
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.xml
```

Please let me know how I can change my code to resolve this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742054/the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a-common-a

Comment: System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; //adding this to your application should be sufficient.

Comment: can i add this in any xml file above?