# An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response on service call from a new server

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, https, tls1.2

The same code works fine on another server so we are trying to figure out what needs to be enabled on the Windows Server 2012 R2. .NET Version used is 4.6.1

This is a service call from one WCF Service to another using basicHttpBinding.

I have reviewed this Quetion & Answer on SO:
[The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742054/the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a-common-a)

However, in my case Tls1.1 & Tls1.2 should be enabled by default since I'm using WinServer2012 R2...(Correct?!)

I have also tried the Microsoft Registry fix but when I try it on the box it says it's not relevant to this server version.

Here is the log with this error:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://*****/EagleOLAPService/EagleOLAPService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---&amp;gt; System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---&amp;gt; System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential&amp;amp; secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]&amp;amp; thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]&amp;amp; output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Comment: The Http service call that is failing is called from a WCF service (that acts as the client for this call)

Comment: Is the client using the same .net framework as the host?

Comment: Have you tried tracing the service?

Comment: When I trace it I get the following error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742054/the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a-common-a