# Error The client and the server cannot communicate, since they do not have a common algorithm

Tags: .net, wpf, ssl, windows-10

I upgraded to a Windows 10 PRO 20H2 computer which has a .net desktop application with wpf. (.net version 4.8) When trying to communicate with a service that only supports SSL3 I get an error. By code I do it as follows

```
/*El ws no soporta tls sino ssl*/
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

/*Como no hay certificado instalado confiar todos*/
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Error that appears in the application log.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error al enviar la solicitud. ---> System.Net.WebException: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de recepción. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: El cliente y el servidor no pueden comunicarse, ya que no poseen un algoritmo común
   en System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
   en System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
   en System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   en System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   en System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   en System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   en System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   en System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   en System.Net.TlsStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   en System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   en System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   en Kiosco.Helpers.LoggedClient.<Post>d__3.MoveNext() |    en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   en Kiosco.Helpers.LoggedClient.<Post>d__3.MoveNext()
```

System events failed
[image]

Comment: Has SSL3 been disabled on the client?

Comment: ["TLS 1.0 was first defined in RFC 2246 in January 1999..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.0)  Maybe it's time to drag that server into the 21st century?  It's already 20% over...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm - ASP.NET C# IIS TLS 1.0 / 1.1 / 1.2 - Win32Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742054/the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a-common-a)