# Does Azure Storage Classic support TLS 1.2?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, tls1.2, azure-cloud-services

I recently disabled TLS older than 1.2 in my service. And the connection to storage account (classic) stopped working with error: "*The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm*".

I am trying to zero in into the cause. I think it's either Azure Storage classic not supporting TLS 1.2 or it could be that the client I am using is old. Any idea if it's the former?

I tried looking up the official docs, but it's hard to find any info on classic storage account.

PS: I know classic storage account is pretty old, but I am stuck with maintaining an older service (a classic cloud service which necessitates a classic storage account).

Screenshot of the overview tab of the storage account:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Classic storage account supports TLS 1.2

[image]

Whenever there is an error like this thrown related to making a secure connection!

[Enforce a minimum required version of Transport Layer Security (TLS) for requests to a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/transport-layer-security-configure-minimum-version?tabs=portal)

[Configure Transport Layer Security (TLS) for a client application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/transport-layer-security-configure-client-version?tabs=powershell)

Based on the error message refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742054/the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a-common-a) thread gives some idea on your scenario.

Comment: In my case, "Account kind: Storage (classic)" which is perhaps older than v1 storage. I tried setting "ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;" as suggested in the SO thread you referenced, but that didn't help. I get the exact same error :(

I don't see the option to set the Minimum TLS version under Configuration. I can see that option in a new storage v2 account, but not in the existing classic account.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: Edited the question to include the screenshot.