# Why calling AWS APIGateway from .Net framework 4.6.1 gives internal server error unlike .net 6.0 gives OK status?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, .net-4.6.1

Why calling AWS APIGateway from .Net framework 4.6.1 gives internal server error unlike .net 6.0 gives OK status.
The same exact code using httpclient & same timeout 30 seconds.

Comment: I got runtime error from .Net 4.6.1:
Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was using httpruntime 4.5.1. I replaced it with 4.6.1 [stackoverflow runtime version issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52763548/3316279)